# Adding prevstate parameter to this.setState causes typeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, typeerror, setstate

I am updating state onchange. setState worked without providing prevstate, but didn't write in the rest of the state values of course. But when I added in prevstate I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
  110 | if(inputs[i].checked && this.state.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`] !== true ) {
  111 |   this.setState(prevstate=>({
  112 |     ...prevstate,
> 113 |     rates: {
      | ^  114 |       ...prevstate.rates,
  115 |       [inputs[i].name]: true
  116 |     }
```

I don't know what is causing this. Here is state and my handleChange function:

```
this.state={
  rawnew:[],
  rawold:[],
  posts: [],
  count: 0,
  report: false,
  rates: {}
}
```

## handleChange function:

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  console.log(this.state)
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, inputs[i].name)
    if (inputs[i].checked && this.state.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`] !== true) {
      this.setState(prevstate => ({
        ...prevstate,
        rates: {
          ...prevstate.rates,
          [inputs[i].name]: true
        }
      }))
    } else if (this.state.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`] !== undefined && this.state.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`] !== inputs[i].checked) {
      this.setState(prevstate => ({
        rates: {
          ...prevstate.rates,
          [inputs[i].name]: !prevstate.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`]
        }
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined `, well, the error comes from this `[inputs[i].name]: true`, have you checked it?

Comment: Remove this line of code var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input') instead use refs to access tags dom node like this:  if(inputs[i].refs.checked && this.state.rates.inputs[i].refs.name !== true ) {   add ref="name" on your input tag.
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous which means the value of `i` may have changed by the time `setState` runs. It also means that `this.state` may not contain the updated values at each iteration. For example when you're checking whether the rate for a name is true:

`` this.state.rates[`${inputs[i].name}`] !== true ``

It's possible that a previous iteration set the value to true but that react hasn't updated `this.state` yet.

Instead of updating the state inside the loop, try building the new state and updating it outside of the loop just once.

Use a `forEach` loop which creates a new scope for each iteration and ensures that `input` has the same contents by the time `setState` runs.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    // see Jesse's comment about using refs
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    const newState = { ...this.state, rates: ...this.state.rates };

    inputs.forEach(input => {
        const { checked, name } = input;
        newState.rates[name] = checked;
    });

    this.setState(newState);
}
```